# Keyboard's space bar doesn't work in Minecraft on husband's computer, but it works on my computer

Tags: keyboard, minecraft

My husband's keyboard's space bar works fine, except in Minecraft.  We thought it was his keyboard, so we got another one, however this one has the same problem.  So we tried both keyboards on my computer and they work just fine, even in Minecraft.  I'm trying to look at the alt-code the keyboard puts out for space, but I can't figure out how to reverse an alt-code.  I'm guessing it's some kind of hardware configuration or driver problem or something, but I'm not very knowledgeable in those areas.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's only in Minecraft than probably the key binding has been misconfigured. Check the settings for keyboard configuration and set as default.

Comment: The key bindings are already set to default.  I forgot to mention that earlier.  Thanks!

Comment: If you map the spacebars function to another key, does it work than? Also mapping another function to the space bar?

Comment: My husband has been using 'F' for the space bar's normal function (jump), so I know that works.  I just tried mapping space to inventory and it actually worked!  I don't know what this means though, or how I can get space to work for jump.

Comment: Could you try mapping jump back to space now?

Comment: Now it works sometimes.  When it does work, it is delayed about half the time.

Comment: are you using an USB hub?

Comment: The keyboard is plugged into the computer directly.  I've tried both the back ports and the front ports.

Comment: I think this still can be a game bug or a driver bug. It seems pretty odd. Next thing to try is connect the new keyboard, enter device manager, and uninstall everything you find in `Keyboards`, than press `Scan for hardware changes`, after it has been reinstalled, right click and `Update driver software`

Comment: I did what you suggested, but unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. Reinstalling Minecraft is my last bet. If you have any further information or news, leave a feedback and maybe it will ring a bell for me or for someone.

Comment: We finally got around to reinstalling Minecraft today.  Still no luck.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: My husband continued looking into this and found the problem.  I've posted the answer.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'm glad the problem has been solved. Have fun. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My husband discovered the problem: he has a program called AutoHotKey that was somehow interfering with the space bar.  Once he turned the AutoHotKey scripts off, space worked fine for jump in Minecraft.